# Comparing strings to string produced by ifstream::getline

Tags: c++, string, input, ifstream

I am working on a project where I need to read postscript and parse data from the file to use in my program. I am working on a function to test whether the postscript is valid by making sure it has opening and closing delimiters.

Below is the segment of code I have written to accomplish this. I am confident that there are no additional spaces or anything of the sort in the postscript file to cause any discrepancy between delimitStr and lineStr. I also attempted to set delimitStr to "%%%BEGIN\0" and "%%%BEGIN", but the comparison never works.

```
string lineStr;
bool beginFlag = false; //Switches to true when begin statement in postscript is found
string delimitStr = "%%%BEGIN"; //Starts as opening  delimiter. Switches to closing when opening is found.
while(psfile) {
    getline(psfile, lineStr);
    if(!beginFlag && lineStr == delimitStr) {
        beginFlag = true;
        delimitStr = "%%%END";
        cerr << "Begin found." << endl;
    }
    else if(beginFlag && lineStr == delimitStr)
        return true; //Only return true if file has beginning and ending delimiters.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note: I have also tried the lineStr and delimitStr comparisons with and without the ".c_str()" suffix.

Comment: The correct line reading idiom is `while (std::getline(psfile, lineStr)) { /*...*/ }`. Your code is off-by-one. Also, strings don't work that way.

Comment: I may adjust that line of code, but it's reading through the file with no problems. The comparison just isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Change `delimitStr` to `delimitStr = "%%%BEGIN";` because `getline` discards the `'\n'`
and
compare strings like this `lineStr == delimitStr`.
DO NOT compare strings with `c_str()` as that returns a `const char*`.

Example showing the differences:

```
std::string s1("%%%BEGIN");
std::string s2("%%%BEGIN\n");
std::string s3("%%%BEGIN\0"); // Same as s1 because std::string stops at '\0'

std::cout << std::boolalpha << (s1 == s2) << '\n';      // Outputs: false
std::cout << (s1 == s3) << '\n';      // Outputs: true 
std::cout << (s2 == s3) << std::endl; // Outputs: false
```

Comment: +1 I did not pick up the problem with how the string was defined.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, but for some reason it still isn't working. I made sure that there were no extra characters trailing the line in the postscript, but for some reason the getline is returning "%%%BEGIN", but lineStr.length() == 9, while delimitStr.length() == 8.

Comment: @user1166271: My only guess is you have an extra space, try outputting the string to the console to verify.